# Bitmap ever return null get image from file path after auto take camera

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I store image auto take camera image.Bimap value ever null after get image from file path.How we can do it? pleases help us.

```
   private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG"
            + timeStamp + ".jpg");

   /* mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".JPEG");*/
    return mediaFile;
}
```

auto take camera method

```
    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

};
```

calling camera onCreate

```
 private Camera mCamera;
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

I already get image picture value /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG20151215_141506.jpg 
when I set to bitmap the bitmap value return null how we can set image file path string to bitmap

```
     picture = getOutputMediaFile().getAbsolutePath();
     File file=new File(picture);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                Bitmap bitmap =       BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),options);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
                String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I'm also try the same like this

```
   picture = getOutputMediaFile().getPath();(OR)
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath);(OR)
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picture);(OR)
```

Comment: `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;`. Remove that. You don't want to decode just the bounds, is it?

Comment: I already test with remove options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;did you have any idea ?

Comment: If bitmap in Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(); becomes null then the bitmap would be to big for available memory. What is the size of the jpg file? What is the resolution of the jpg image? You should check for null before you continue. Do not blindly execute that compress() statement.

Comment: Check if the file exists before use. `if ( ! file.exists() ) Toast file does not exist i will not continue`

Comment: Do you really have TWO call to `getOutputMediaFile()` ? That is not possible as the time has changed in between so the paths will be different. Use it only once.

Comment: Thanks... how can check image size and resolution for bitmap available memory

Comment: The Gallery app will tell you. `What is the size of the jpg file? What is the resolution of the jpg image?`Then tell us as we asked for that.

Comment: you don't help me anything for that?Now I'm so tried for that

Comment: What help do you need for that? Just answer my questions. React to my suggestions. What's difficult?

Comment: How can set image path file into bitmap?